# In Elixir, why not use case statements instead of multiple function overloading?

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir and a little confused as to why we must branch using multiple definitions of the same function, instead of using the case statement. Here is an example from [Elixir in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/elixir-in-action), first edition page 81, for counting the lines in a file:

```
defmodule LinesCounter do
  def count(path) do
    File.read(path)
    |> lines_num
  end

  defp lines_num({:ok, contents}) do
    contents
    |> String.split("\n")
    |> length
  end

  defp lines_num({:error, _}), do: "error"
 end
```

So we have two defp lines_num instances to handle the cases of :ok and :error. But doesn't the following do the same thing, arguably in a cleaner, and more concise way, and using only one function instead of three?

```
defmodule LinesCounterCase do
  def count(file) do
    case File.read(file) do
      {:ok, contents} -> contents |> String.split("\n") |> length
      {:error, _} -> "error"
    end
  end
end
```

Both work identically.

I don't want to learn incorrect idioms as I start out my journey on Elixir so clarifying the downsides of using the case statement in this way, is what I am looking for.

Comment: I prefer the case version as well ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code from book is not very idiomatic and it tries to show multiple function clauses and pipes on example that is not the best.

### Part1: Separation of concerns.

First thing is that general convention says that pipes should start with "raw" variable like this:

```
def count(path) do
  path
  |> File.read
  |> lines_num
end
```

Second thing is that this code really mixes responsibilities. Sometimes it is also good to thing about types returned by functions. If I saw, that `lines_num` returns integer or string, I would really scratch my head. Why `lines_num` should care about error while reading the file? The answer is: it shouldn't. It should take a string and return what it calculated:

```
defp lines_num(contents) do #skipping the tuple here
  contents
  |> String.split("\n")
  |> length
end
```

Now you have two options in your count function. You can either let it crash when there is a problem with file or handle the error. In this example there is only string "error" returned, so the most idiomatic way would be to skip it completely:

```
def count(path) do
  path
  |> File.read! #note the "!" it means it will return just content instead {:ok, content} or rise an error
  |> lines_num
  end
end
```

Elixir almost always provides `func!` version and it is exactly for that reason - to make it easier to pipe things.

If you want to handle the error, case statement is the best. Unix pipes also don't encourage branching.

```
def count(path) do
  case File.read(path) do
    {:ok, contents} -> lines_num(contents)
    {:error, reason} -> do_something_on_error(reason)
  end
end
```

### Part2: Where multiple function clauses make sense?

There are two main cases where multiple function clauses are superior to case statements: recursion and polymorphism. There are some others, but those should be enough for a beginner.

#### Polymorphism

Suppose you want to make the `lines_num` more generic to also handle the list of chars representation:

```
defp lines_num(contents) when is_binary(contents) do
  ...
end
defp lines_num(contents) when is_list(contents) do
  contents
  |> :binary.list_to_bin #not the most efficient way!
  |> lines_num
end
```

The implementation might be different, but the end result will be the same: number of lines for different types: `"foo \n bar"` and `'foo \n bar'`.

#### Recursion

```
def factorial(0), do: 0
def factorial(n), do: n * factorial(n-1)

def map([], _func), do: []
def map([head, tail], func), do: [func.(head), map(tail)]
```

(Warning: examples are not tail recursive) Using case for such functions would be much less readable/idiomatic.

### Conclusion:

1. Don't use function heads for branching logic unless you know what you are doing.
2. If you have branching logic it is better to split pipes.
3. Use function clauses for polymorphism and recursion.

Comment: Something that might warrant adding: if you have a nested case statement, you need to break it apart into separate functions. Nested case statements quickly become a tangled ball of mud.

Comment: That is true, but I think it is a separate concern and doesn't answer the question when to use case vs function clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a point here that the three-body version here is better at producing functions that have a single responsibility. I think this is one of the most important principles in software design and holds for classes (and similar constructs) in OO as well as for functions in FP. The case-statement version is shorter and more concise, but does combine file reading and line counting in one go. Try to write a test for it, and then for the version that's split up.

It's a design question, of course. YMMV. But I think that a book needs to err on the safe side, and here there's a decent trade-off between applying SRP and being concise.

Comment: Since the `lines_num` function is private, I would say the testing argument is not valid. SRP is a good point though.

Comment: @Patrick Oscity. I don't see how SRP is maintained in the overloaded version though. It does not cleanly break the task into independent actions and farm them out to different functions. Instead we have file opening *and* line count call in one function, then we have file existence error-case checking *and* line count implementation in others. They're all very much intertwined with each other, and that violates SRP in my opinion.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne sorry for the confusion, you're absolutely correct. I meant SRP is a good thing in general. Was on mobile and am right now so a bit lazy about typing :)

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance, it may not make a difference which way you do it. There isn't anything that says you "must" use pattern matching function clauses.

The `case` statement version is more similar to how other languages would do this, so the author may have been introducing an Elixir specific concept in anticipation of making more use of it later.

I definitely prefer the multiple function clause version, but maybe that's because I've been looking at Erlang and Elixir code for a while and have gotten used to seeing it.

I asked on the Elixir Slack channel what reasons there were for choosing functions over `case` statements and the recommendation was to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQyt9Vlkbis

The main argument for using function clauses over a `case` statement is that you can give a name to the decision you're making. The example given in this question isn't as compelling on that point, but the video lays it out very well.